# Why does std::vector CTAD accept both int and double?

Tags: c++, c++17, ctad

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector v{2, 3.14};
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

    std::cout << "size: " << v.size() << '\n';
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << "- " << x << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >
size: 2
- 2
- 3.14
```

`std::vector` instantiation uses auto-type-deduction (CTAD).

Apparently, the `initializer_list` constructor is used (checked), but why does it accept both an `int` and a `double` and still deduces the type as `vector<double>` ?
If I increase the number of elements (while mixing `int` and `double`), compilation fails.

The same result with `gcc` and `clang`

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.0.1 20230401 (Red Hat 13.0.1-0)

$ clang++ --version
clang version 16.0.1 (Fedora 16.0.1-1.fc38)
```

Comment: try `std::vector v{5, 3.14};` :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Same result. size: 2, contains 5 & 3.14

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it? Have you tried with other compilers? What options do you pass when building, more specifically which C++ standard are you asking the compiler to use?

Comment: which version of the compiler?

Comment: @Tootsie right, I didnt pay attention, or I dont know what I did differerntly previously https://godbolt.org/z/7r8qTbdGe

Comment: Questions edited with compiler versions for gcc and clang

Comment: I would argue this is because a built-in ambiguity in the C++ specification with argument deduction and overload resolution.

Comment: Check [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/a1c1a0ea) this uses constructor overload with initialization list! In brace initialization case initialization list has priority over other ctor overloads.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two instances of overload resolution happening here. The first is to deduce the template argument. Since the two types in the init-list are different, the size+value constructor (or more formally, the deduction guide generated from said constructor) is picked here, deducing the type to be `double`.

Then overload resolution runs again to create the object. With the type now known as `double`, the list constructor is now valid, and thus used to initialize the object.

Comment: So if you wanted to get a vector of size 2, filled with values all equal to 3.14, would you be forced to explicitly indicate the template argument as `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica, I believe using parentheses instead of braces would do that because the list constructor is removed from the picture entirely.

Comment: So you are saying that two different constructors are used for template type deduction and initialization. Shouldn't the same constructor be used for both actions? I can't get my head over this.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan, It is a little weird. I can't say why it doesn't require that.

Comment: Can you provide any section in standard with will address this issue, or at least some non-official resources? I would be very thankful.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan, I was deliberately avoiding the standard itself on this one because there's no telling how long I'd be trapped in there, but I can offer [this CppCon video](https://youtu.be/-H-ut6j1BYU?t=1955) (at the relevant slide). I wonder if the proposal has motivation for allowing different results when a constructor or its generated guide is chosen in both cases or if the idea was to layer CTAD on top and that fell out as just a consequence.